# What middle-ware do you recommend for a swarm of AUVs?

Tags: mobile-robot, ros

Working with a swarm of robots, collaboration between the nodes is really important(either for the goal of simulation or real-word operation). Middle-wares are the frameworks for this special purpose. I know some of the relevant middle-wares like ROS(general-purpose but popular) or uMVS(that is basically design for AUVs). Now, I have two questions:

1. Do you know any other choice for the above mentioned purpose?
2. What criteria should I consider for choosing a middle-ware suitable for my purpose?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link to the project you are working on?

Comment: Unfortunately the project have no page on the internet!

Answer (score 2):

To your first question if there is something other:
We are using for AUV control the middleware framework work named rock:

http://www.rock-robotics.org

The main problem in general is the weak communication between AUVs.
You have really limited bandwidths available.

Your question in unclear which kind of information do you wand to exchange (and how). I know currently no framework which supports data-exchange on real-low bandwidths. The Communication between AUVs is a special case, and should not be fullfilled by a framework.

If you plan to do multi-agent setups (where is client is autonomous after the start) the framework plays no special rule, since there is no communication between the vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

Communication between swarms of AUVs is an open problem, because you are trying to build a reliable communications network out of unreliable links.  Between the time that I did an undergraduate thesis on this (multiple cooperating AUVs) and the present day, there are currently no middlewares that address this issue -- all of them assume flawless communication between nodes.

In other words, you are trying to simultaneously arrange the nodes in a way that will allow them to communicate, and communicate to find how to arrange the nodes for the purposes of the mission.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if their software can extend to AUVs, but the [Rice University Multi-Robot Systems Lab](http://mrsl.rice.edu/) has done very advanced things with robot swarms.